# update Jenkins build parameter via remote API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a method to remotely update a build parameter for a Jenkins jobs after the job has started (or even after the job has completed perhaps).

Looking over the API docs, I have seen plenty of examples of doing a GET to retrieve information, and some examples of doing a POST to trigger build configurations to run.

I'm struggling to find any examples or information on whether it's possible to set information such as a parameter via API, e.g. using POST.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by parameter, perhaps with a specific example of the problems you're trying to solve? You can launch a parameterized build (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) with a POST, but you can't change the parameter once the build has started.

Comment: In reality, all I want to do is to store 2 or 3 small ID numbers back to the jenkins job as part of the build process. These ID numbers could then be made available to view via the GUI.

Comment: I was thinking to have some additional build parameters which are empty by default when build is triggered, but then get set via a POST as part of build. From what you say above, sounds like this may not be possible in this way, and I should look for some alternative thinking.

Comment: Okay, seems that the 'build description' can be set via the web API. This is sufficient for me to use whilst doing some prototype experiments.  curl -s "http://<hostname>/job/<jobname>/1/submitDescription?desciption=newtextfordescription"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

The only thing I can think of is to get the config.xml, update the parts you need then submit that config file.

Not pretty!

Comment: The entire software/hardware project was cancelled, negating the need for a continuous integration system, which is one way to solve the problem I suppose.